# why do I get this error: please make sure ActiveModel::Naming is included

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, naming, activemodel

I am installing a gem called completeness-fu.

This is the error I get:

```
completeness-fu-0.6.0/lib/completeness-fu/active_model_additions.rb:12:in `define_completeness_scoring': please make sure ActiveModel::Naming is included so completeness_scoring can translate messages correctly (CompletenessFu::CompletenessFuError)
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveModel::Naming` [creates a `#model_name` method on your object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html). The completeness-fu gem seems to require it for the `#define_completeness_scoring` method.

From [the readme](https://github.com/joshk/completeness-fu/blob/master/readme.markdown):

> Completeness-Fu used to be for ActiveRecord only, but this has changed with the latest version with only ActiveModel needed as a gem dependency (and a little ActiveSupport). This means that the latest version works with the following ORMs :
>
> - ActiveRecord
> - Mongoid
> - Cassandra Object
>
> The `define_completeness_scoring method` is mixed into the above mentioned ORMs by default, but if you want to use Completeness-Fu in an `ActiveModel` model which isn't one of the above ORMs, make sure you include `ActiveModel::Naming`. If you want to cache the completeness score make sure you also include `ActiveModel::Validations` and `ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks`.

## Updated

See comments; the underlying issue seems to be a bug in the gem (as of 29 June, 2011). This could be monkey-patched using the following code (assuming Ruby 1.9). The only change is using `self.singleton_class.include?(ActiveModel::Naming)` to get the proper response.

```
# lib/completeness-fu.rb
module CompletenessFu
  module ActiveModelAdditions
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        def self.define_completeness_scoring(&checks_block)
          # The check below is causing the problem; the simplest fix in Ruby 1.8
          # would be to simply remove it by commenting out the following 3 lines.
          unless self.singleton_class.include?(ActiveModel::Naming)
            raise CompletenessFuError, 'please make sure ActiveModel::Naming is included so completeness_scoring can translate messages correctly'
          end

          class_inheritable_array :completeness_checks
          cattr_accessor :default_weighting
          cattr_accessor :model_weightings

          self.send :extend, ClassMethods
          self.send :include, InstanceMethods

          checks_results = CompletenessFu::ScoringBuilder.generate(self, &checks_block)

          self.default_weighting   = checks_results[:default_weighting]
          self.completeness_checks = checks_results[:completeness_checks]
          self.model_weightings    = checks_results[:model_weightings]

          if checks_results[:cache_score_details]
            unless self.include?(ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks)
              raise CompletenessFuError, 'please make sure ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks is included before define_completeness_scoring if you want to cache competeness scoring'
            end
            self.before_validation checks_results[:cache_score_details]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### Warning!!!

This is a super temporary (and fragile) monkey-patch, and I *really* don't recommend actually using code like this in a production capacity.

The better options would be to find a different gem for this, work with the author to get it fixed, fork the project and fix it yourself then use that fork in your project ([more info](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-end-of-monkeypatching-4570.html)) or simply rebuild this functionality in your app locally using the gem as a starting design.

Comment: Looking at the gem's code, it throws the error when `self.include?(ActiveModel::Naming)` returns `false`. Unfortunately, `ActiveModel::Naming` is just `extended` so it's `#include?` returns `false`. It's a bug in the gem.

Comment: I see, I see....so this can't be fixed without fixing the gem?  I tried to add your extend activemodel to my activerecord but i stil got the error :(

Comment: I added a possible short-term work-around that monkey-patches the gem. I *really* don't suggest using it in a production capacity though. If you can't wait for the author to fix the gem, I would fork it and fix it yourself, then use your version of it in your app ([more info](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-end-of-monkeypatching-4570.html))

Comment: I see --- thanks for your help!  I am using ruby 1.8.7 -- been having trouble installing rvm so staying with it until I figure out what's going on... :)

Comment: I added comments above the `unless` line that is causing the problem. Since getting the `#singleton_class` equivalent in 1.8 would require more meta-programming that might be more confusing than it's worth for you currently, I'd simply remove the `ActiveModel::Naming` check entirely for now. Again; proceed with caution!

Comment: Hi Guys, I am the author of completeness-fu. I have been a bit busy to take a look into this issue, but an any case I do gladly accept pull requests (fork and fix). I will have a look into this issue and update the GitHub issue this weekend.